# Sqlite - getting Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

i'm trying to get one contact from my db, i keep getting Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 error.

this is my code:

```
// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]
                    { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_FULLNAME, COLUMN_PHONE, COLUMN_EMAIL, COLUMN_ADDRESS, COLUMN_SITE, COLUMN_BIRTHDAY },
                    COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);


    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1),
            cursor.getString(2),
            cursor.getString(3),
            cursor.getString(4),
            cursor.getString(5),
            cursor.getString(6));
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return contact;
}
```

this is the error i'm getting:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

plz help me understand what to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query did not match any data.

Check the result of `moveTo...()` to learn whether the cursor is pointing to a valid row: the method call returns false if the move did not succeed. To make the query match data and return rows, check your query selection criteria.

Also, `SQLiteDatabase` query methods never return a `null` for a `Cursor` so the `!= null` checks are redundant.

Comment: how do i check if its pointing to a valid row?
and how do i make it point to one?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Try this method, it should work.

```
Contact getContact(int id) {
    Contact contact = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = " + id;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        contact = new Contact(
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getString(4),
                cursor.getString(5),
                cursor.getString(6));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return contact;
}
```

---

Maybe change:

```
if (cursor != null) 
    cursor.moveToFirst();
```

with:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
```

As for this [Android Reference on Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29), moveToFirst() returns false if the cursor is emtpy.

Answer (score 0):

May be your table is empty.

Try to change the condition to

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{

    Contact contact = new Contact(
        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
        cursor.getString(1),
        cursor.getString(2),
        cursor.getString(3),
        cursor.getString(4),
        cursor.getString(5),
        cursor.getString(6)); 
}
```

Comment: @LirazShakaAmir Can you check size of cursor and tell me what it returns, using `cursor.getCount()` , you can use log `Log.d("Cursor Count: ",cursor.getCount().toString);` (remove or comment the code that tigers the error first).